# AngularJS globally modify the URL of every request in $http

Tags: angularjs

Let's set up a simple example:

```
$scope.whatDoesTheFoxSay = function(){
    $http.post("/backend/ancientMystery", {
...
```

How can I globally transform the URL where the post request is sent to? Essentially I want to prepend an URL to every http request.

What I have tried is setting a variable in the `$rootScope` containing the url when the application starts. But this is not what I want my code to look like:

```
$scope.whatDoesTheFoxSay = function(){
    $http.post($rootScope.backendUrl + "/backend/hidingDeepInTheWoods", {
...
```

Am I correct assuming that I should look into `$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest`? Can anyone provide me with some basic example code?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I have another approach of using request interceptor with $http which will handle all the url's at one common place

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="test">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>

  </head>
 <body ng-controller="test" >    


<!-- tabs -->


 <script>
     var app = angular.module('test', []);
     app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
         $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
             return {
                 'request': function (config) {
                     config.url = config.url + '?id=123';
                     return config || $q.when(config);

                 }

             }
         });
     });

     app.controller('test', function ($scope,$http) {
         $http.get('Response.txt').success(function (data) { alert(data) }).error(function (fail) {

         });
     });

   </script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: When using this along with `ngToast` I get the error `Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'toast' must have exactly one root element`

Comment: ```config.url = config.url + '?id=123'; return config || $q.when(config);``` Right after accessing ```config.url```, what would make ```config``` evaluate to false?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem of "cache-busting in AngularJS" and wanted to share a working solution that also includes an option to 'un-cache' `$templatecache` resources.

This solution correctly returns a value and not a promise `;)` and doesn't form malformed URL's if your request already contains `$_GET` values.

```
var __version_number = 6.0; // Date.now('U'); // 'U' -> linux/unix epoch date int

app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function () {
    return {
      'request': function (config) {
        // !!config.cached represents if the request is resolved using 
        //      the angular-templatecache
        if (!config.cached) {
          config.url += ( (config.url.indexOf('?') > -1) ? '&' : '?' ) 
            + config.paramSerializer({v: __version_number});
        } else if (config.url.indexOf('no-cache') > -1) {
          // if the cached URL contains 'no-cache' then remove it from the cache
          config.cache.remove(config.url);
          config.cached = false; // unknown consequences
          // Warning: if you remove the value form the cache, and the asset is not
          //          accessable at the given URL, you will get a 404 error.
        }
        return config;
      }
    }
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A modern day approach would be to implement a custom `Http` client.

```
export function getCustomHttp(xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions) {
    return new CustomHttp(xhrBackend, requestOptions);
}

export class CustomHttp extends Http {
    public constructor(backend: XHRBackend, private defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    public request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        url = 'https://www.customURL.com/' + url; // Of course, you'd pull this from a config
        return super.request(url, options);
    }
}
```

Then you would simply modify your `app.module` as follows:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoute,
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [
    HttpModule,
    {
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: getCustomHttp,
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```