# Global configuring $http for using CORS in angularJS (fixed domain for all requests)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, httprequest

I have ad restful server and a web server in another domain for serving asset files.

In past both of this servers was same and serves in one server. and now I try to change the relative URLs to Explicit one.

Ordinary solution is changing all used URLs like this:

```
$http.post(DATA_SERVER_DOMAIN+"/service/method" )
```

instead of

```
$http.post("/service/method" )
```

is there any solution to set fixed domain for all `$http` or `$resource` requests in angularJS (for example in $httpprovider)

Comment: I'd go with encapsulating all the service requests inside a `$resource`. Then you just use the full URI in there

Comment: You can look at $http request interceptor concept. But you need a mechanism, where you can differential between a your api request vs requests made by framework itself

Comment: I concur with @Phil, and would attempt to wrap requests in a `$resource` (or `$service`)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984518/angularjs-globally-modify-the-url-of-every-request-in-http

Answer (score 1):

I really suggest using the [**Restangular Library**](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) if you want functionality like this and a better coding experience.

It allows you to set different base urls for each service you create.

**[Reference](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#setbaseurl)**.

While this may not be exactly what you're looking for at the moment, you'll be happy you took my advice.