# Spring app doesn't know about angularJS project in the same solution

Tags: angularjs, spring, generator, yo

I have generated a simple angularJS project via [AngularJS generator by yoeman](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular#readme)

and after that created simple Spring-boot project with JPA repository which has one controller mehod with funcionality to select all users. The case is when I run both projects - spring on port 8080 and angular project on port 9000, there is no chance how the angular project can get to know about the data which spring is throwing.

My file tree in a project looks like:

[image]

And I think the problem is with index.html file. Normally it should be putted in a resource folder, so that spring project could communicate with angular project. But during grunt commend in cmd the build folder creates a new index.html file and the process makes circle. I thought about moving index.html file into resource folder but it doesn't make sense anymore.

I also thougt about changing the Gruntfile.js but honestly I don't know what excatly should I change. The Gruntfile looks like: [Link to pastebin because the file was too long](http://pastebin.com/iPtjaMdu)

Simple service:

```
angular.module('webappApp')
  .factory('myroute', function ($resource) {
    var service = $resource('/api/user', { id : '@id'},
      {


      });

    return service;
  });
```

Simple controller:

```
angular.module('webappApp')
  .controller('MyrouteCtrl', function (myroute) {
    console.log(myroute.query());
  });
```

Comment: what do you mean by "there is no chance how the angular project can get to know about the data which spring is throwing." ? You should be requesting through ajax request data to the java backend

Comment: I'm asking about them in js controller through $resource

Comment: ok, show us that code

Comment: Simple service: 
`angular.module('webappApp')
  .factory('myroute', function ($resource) {
    var service = $resource('/api/user', { id : '@id'},
      {


      });

    return service;
  });`
Simple controller: 
`angular.module('webappApp')
  .controller('MyrouteCtrl', function (myroute) {
    console.log(myroute.query());
  });`

Comment: update your question with that data

Comment: I have updated of above service and controller code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS globally modify the URL of every request in $http](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984518/angularjs-globally-modify-the-url-of-every-request-in-http)

Comment: Actually I don't think so..

Comment: you are making ajax request to your port 9000 - but your backend is set in another url. you need to update your url requests

Answer (score 0):

You need set in grunt proxy for endoints. For example [grunt-connect-proxy](https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy)

Add something like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    connect: {
        server: {
            options: {
                port: 8080,
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
            proxies: [
                {
                    context: '/api',
                    host: 'localhost',
                    port: 8080,
                    https: false
                }
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

But this you need only for local development.

Comment: Is it possbile to run spring project and angular both on port 8080? I don't think so it is possbile, so I can't imagine how it will be possible to work with?

Comment: It is possible, check this [Spring Boot and AngularJS Integration Tutorial](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/boot/spring-boot-and-angularjs-integration-tutorial/) or this [Spring and Angular JS: A Secure Single Page Application](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/spring-and-angular-js-a-secure-single-page-application).

Comment: At first example the index.html file is in resource. At my example it's diffrent - so I can't get that example as a help in my case :(
At the second example I can't see any commons..

Comment: Or maybe the UI should be in a resources/static folder?

Comment: For example when I created a project via jhipster generator, it creates all "frontend" files in excatly the same path as above in a question

Comment: I have added the proxies statement and still doesn't work :(