# Calling REST API from Different domain like angular JS with relative URL

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, spring-mvc

I have written REST API using spring mvc which is hosted on one domain and Front end is written using HTML and angular JS which is hosted on another domain.Now I want to call REST API from another domain on which Frond UI is placed so how can I call REST API using relative URI instead of absolute URI?

For e.g.Instaed of

```
webbrokerModule.factory('CustomerContact', [ '$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:24000/webbroker/customercontact/:brokerid', {
        brokerid : '@brokerid'
    }, {
        get : {
            method : 'GET'
        }
    });
} ]);

I want to call it as 
webbrokerModule.factory('CustomerContact', [ '$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/webbroker/customercontact/:brokerid', {
        brokerid : '@brokerid'
    }, {
        get : {
            method : 'GET'
        }
    });
} ]);
```

I do not want to mention IP address and PORT.

Comment: Check that answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984518/angularjs-globally-modify-the-url-of-every-request-in-http

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a factory or a service of hardcoded resources.

For instance :

```
angular
.module('app')
.factory('storage', storageFactory);

function storageFactory() {

var r =
{
    serverAdress : 'https://server.address.fr',
    //serverAdress : 'https://another.server.adress.fr',
    //serverAdress : 'http://localhost:3000',
};

return r;

}
```

Example of usage :

```
$http.get(storage.serverAdress + '/relative/path').then(function(res)...
```

This way you can encapsulate all your hardcoded data and change them more easily depending on your Environment variables (for instance if you want a different serveur address for the test server or something).

It is also very simple if one day you want to change your domains. This kind of practice is called a thin layer.

Comment: Is there anything like bootstraping application which will allow me to use relative url.right now i have 3 different environmemt so i need to have 3 different file as per your logic

Comment: Nope, not at all, just change the serverAddress in the js file at runtime if you are in a different environment

Comment: Just check how tu use process_env variables and use that var instead of hardcoding serverAdress is the file. This way the serverAdress in the file will always refer to a linux environment variable. Your job to declare it in your run script when launching in the environment, but that is pretty easy :)